# Numpy 3darray matrix multiplication function

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, vectorization, multiplication

Suppose I have an ndarray, W of shape (m,n,n) and a vector C of dimension (m,n). I need to multiply these two in the following way

```
result = np.empty(m,n)
for i in range(m):
    result[i] = W[i] @ C[i]
```

How do I do this in a vectorized way without loops and all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since, you need to keep the first axis from both `W` and `C` aligned, while loosing the last axis from them with the matrix-multiplication, I would suggest using [`np.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) for a very efficient approach, like so -

`np.einsum('ijk,ik->ij',W,C`)

`np.tensordot` or `np.dot` doesn't have the feature to keep axes aligned and that's where `np.einsum` improves upon.

Answer (score 0):

`np.dot` should be your friend.
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html

Answer (score 0):

It's done using np.tensordot

```
ans=np.tensordot(W,C,axes=[2,1])[np.arange(m),:,np.arange(m)]
assert np.all(result==ans)
```